# Prove that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ with equal, non-zero modulus, are vertices of an equilateral triangle if and only if $\sum_{cyc}|z_1-z_2|(z_1+z_2) = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, triangles, roots-of-unity

Prove that $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb C$ , distinct, with equal, non-zero modulus, are vertices of equilateral triangle if and only if $\sum_{cyc}|z_1-z_2|(z_1+z_2) = 0 $

I tried dividing by $z_3|z_3|\ne0$ and I obtained $$|a-b|(a+b)+|a-1|(a+1)+|b-1|(b+1)=0\text{, where }a=\frac{z_1}{z_3}, b=\frac{z_2}{z_3}, |a|=|b|=1$$

The equivalent condition for the triangle to be equilateral is: 
$$z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_1z_3\text{,  equivalent to} $$
$$a^2+b^2+1= ab+a+b $$

The last condition could be written as $(a-b)^2+(a-1)(b-1)=0$

Surely, I need to prove that the equation in the title implies that the triangle is equilateral. The implication from the fact that the triangle is equilateral, resulting the equation, is obvious.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629120/hz-z-a-z-b-z-c-max-value-of-h-is-attained/3065154#3065154) might help.

Comment: Isn't there a non-revealed assumption? Why am I asking? Consider $z_1=z_2.$ From the equation we get $z_3=z_1$ which is a degenerate equilateral triangle, or $z_3=-z_1$ which doesn't define a triangle at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, they are distinct too.